# how to make sub menu appear when hover over link?

Tags: css

how do i make a sub menu dissapear and appear when i hover over a link?

this is my menu:

```
<div class="sideMenu2">
      <ul>
        <li><a href>retail</a>
                <ul class="subsideMenu2">
                            <li>cabot circus</li>
                            <li>st. stephen&#39;s</li>
                            <li>silverburn</li>
                            <li>braehead</li>
                </ul>
        </li>
            <li><a href>sports &amp; leisure</a>
                <ul class="subsideMenu2">
                </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>  
      </div>
```

This is my current css:

```
    .sideMenu2 ul li.on a
{
    height:2em;
    padding-top: 2px;
    background:url(../images/point.png) no-repeat;
    font-weight:bold;   
}

.sideMenu2 ul
{    
    padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;  
    list-style-type:none;
    font-size:0.9em;
    width:20em;
    color:#fff;   
    margin-left:-10px;
}

.sideMenu2 ul a{
    padding: 2px 20px 0px 0px;  
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    float:left;
    width:19.2em;
}

.sideMenu2 li a
{
    height:2em;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-left:15px;
}

.sideMenu2 li a:hover{
    background:url(../images/point.png) no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer; 
    padding-left:-15px;

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
.subsideMenu2 {
  display: none;
}

.sideMenu2 li:hover .subsideMenu2 {
  display: block;
}
```

But won't work in old Internet Explorer, for them the only option is javascript.

Comment: You can style it as always, for example using `.subsideMenu2` class. Sometimes you have to absolutely position the submenu inside the relative positioned parent `li`, otherwise when the sumenu appears on hover everything is a mess.

Comment: erm if the item is selected how do i display the menu then ?

Comment: You should apply a `class` to selected item, and then apply as well `display: block` to `.sideMenu2 li.selected .subsideMenu2`. There is no secret, it's CSS as always.

Answer (score 0):

see this example script of header menu dropdwon style

http://bit.ly/1abEJ9o