# Display div on hovering anchor tag

Tags: html, css

I want to display a div on hovering the anchor tag using css. Below is my html code

```
<td class="cellStyle">
<a href="#" class="linkStyle">
    <div>Home</div>
    <div style="display:none;">I'm here... (some html) </div>
</a></td>
```

Please tell me how i can achieve this using css.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make sub menu appear when hover over link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296230/how-to-make-sub-menu-appear-when-hover-over-link)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give your hidden div a class:

```
<td class="cellStyle">
<a href="#" class="linkStyle">
    <div>Home</div>
    <div class="demo">I'm here... (some html) </div>
</a></td>
```

And use these styles:

```
<style>
a.linkStyle div.demo { display:none; }
a.linkStyle:hover div.demo { display:block; }
</style>
```

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6pB8G/

Answer (score 0):

[how to make sub menu appear when hover over link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296230/how-to-make-sub-menu-appear-when-hover-over-link)

**CSS**

```
a.linkStyle:hover div.here {
    display:block;
}

div.here {
    display : none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="linkStyle">
    <div>Home</div>
    <div class="here">I'm here... (some html) </div>
</a>
```

(Added a class to div which is to be hidden first)

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/euBk6/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**CSS:**

```
.hiddendiv {display:none;}
.linkStyle:hover > .hiddendiv { display:block; }
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="linkStyle">
    <div>Home</div>
    <div class="hiddendiv">I'm here... (some html) </div>
</a>
```

here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EbGq6/)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to **keep block level elements outside from inline elements**. So, try keeping DIV outside from A.

here is demo:

**HTML**

```
<td>    
    <a class="tooltip">Home</a>
    <div class="tip">I'm here... (some html)</div>
</td>
```

**CSS:**

```
.tip{display:none}
.tooltip:hover + .tip{display:block}
```

[<kbd>Working Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/QkkUz/)